# Can the convergence of $\sum a_n$ imply the convergence of $\sum n a_n^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n\geq 0 ~(n\geq 1)$ be a non-negative sequence. Suppose $\sum a_n$ converges; can we deduce that $\sum n a_n^2$ converges?

I have no idea how to solve this analysis exercise, can anyone give me some hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Limit comparison test will get you a lot of mileage here

Comment: The answer is “yes” if $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2716919.

Comment: In the general case a counterexample is given in this (deleted) question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2484070/42969: $a_n=\begin{cases}\frac1{k^2}&\text{if }n=k^4\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: Oh I understand! Thanks for all answers!!